# trouble when searching numbers with regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a text in my document in notepad++ by regular expression but it can't find it.

my document looks like that (the same idea but much longer):

```
<ObjectsGroup name="1_Color">
<InfoAtt AttInfo="1" AttName="INDEX"/>
<Categories>
<Category Probability="0.664914" Name="pen"/>
<Category Probability="0.0757796" Name="switch"/>
<Category Probability="0.0447911" Name="keyboard"/>
</Categories>
</ObjectsGroup>
<ObjectsGroup name="1_Color">
<InfoAtt AttInfo="1" AttName="INDEX"/>
<Categories>
<Category Probability="0.530971" Name="computer bag"/>
<Category Probability="0.144546" Name="computer monitor"/>
<Category Probability="0.097265" Name="mug"/>
</Categories>
</ObjectsGroup>
<ObjectsGroup name="1_Color">
<InfoAtt AttInfo="1" AttName="INDEX"/>
<Categories>
<Category Probability="0.412404" Name="table"/>
<Category Probability="0.343684" Name="pillows"/>
<Category Probability="0.175472" Name="chair"/>
</Categories>
</ObjectsGroup>
```

I want to find all the places that the table is the first in the category list.

I wrote that expression in the find window:

```
 <Categories> 

<Category Probability"(\d*[.]\d*)" Name="table"/>
```

But it didn't find it .

Can someone help me please?

Comment: `<Category Probability="([0-9]*[.][0-9]*)" Name="table"/>`

Comment: If you don't know what might be in the category, just use a non-greedy regex to get everything between the two end strings: `<Category Probability="(.*?)" Name="table"\/>`. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lR6sS1/1)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Thanks! that is the correct answer!

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `/` before the last `>`.

Comment: @sideroxylon, yes I did it.

Comment: That's the reason your regex failed (as well as the missing `=` after `Probability`).  Also, the `[.]` should have been `\.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `\d` to `[0-9]`.

That is the way to say digit in regular expression.

Comment: `\d` is a usual character class for "digit", although it may also match non-latin digits.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it:

```
<Category Probability="([0-9]*[.][0-9]*)" Name="table"/>
```

Comment: `<Category Probability="([0-9]*[.][0-9]*)" Name="table"\/>`

Comment: No need escaping ``/`` in Notepad++ regex pattern, as the forward slash has no special meaning in regex.